# Access denied to a website using tor

Tags: python, cloudflare, tor, pycurl

I am trying to make a bot that requests a url through tor. I have configured tor.
Below is the python code.

```
import pycurl
curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, URL)
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, '127.0.0.1')
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 9050)
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME)
curl.perform()
```

It gives html file with, access denied | url used cloudflare to restrict access.

But when the same url is accessed through browser with tor configured, the url is successfully accessed.

Is there a way out to access the URL using the python script?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the user_agent of pycurl, like:

```
curl.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0')
```

Comment: You might want to send a more updated useragent...  `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0`

Comment: Why would you care about this? Does Cloudflare check such things?

Comment: I don't know if CloudFlare does specifically but all major sites do for many, many reasons. One to try and stop automation and web crawling. @user2358582